# why do previous printing statements show up in new projects build console - android studio/flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, console

So whenever I try to build a new flutter app, i see all the printing statements i have printed in the console from previous projects show up. while building my new project which has nothing to do with this new one,  I have encountered this and many other problems since clicking the (invalidate cache and restart) button from Files.

any idea how to fix it and why that happened??

Comment: Not exactly sure..but my guess is its probably a buffer being flushed out..

Comment: so theres no way i can fix it?